# How to create a Class with a function and export it

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I need to create a lot of similar classes, but they need to be different classes. I could create a class and then inherit all the others from that one but I want to cut down the boilerplate even more, so the idea is to create a function that creates this class (not an instance of it but literally a class) and returns it.

What I have so far:

```
export function createErrorAction(type) {
  return class {
    type = type;
    payload: { error: string};
    constructor(error: string) {
      this.payload = { error : error };
    }
  }
}
```

then I generate and export the different classes:

```
export const LoginErrorAction = createErrorAction(ActionTypes.LOGIN_ERROR);
export const FetchErrorAction = createErrorAction(ActionTypes.FETCH_ERROR);
```

When I want to use this class it works only like this:

```
let foo = new LoginErrorAction("foo");
```

But when I try to add the type I get an error (*Namespace '...path_to_file...' has no exported member LoginErrorAction*):

```
let foo: LoginErrorAction = new LoginErrorAction("foo");
```

Is there something I am missing? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Interesting question, that I can't answer. But I don't think creating many classes is the best strategy. I'd rather use a single class and use the factory method pattern instead: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/f0d65629ed0ee12db094d65c445f7b75

Comment: @JBNizet Good idea, but I need to have the exact type (e.g. LoginErrorAction) of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the type:

```
let foo: --> LoginErrorAction <-- = new LoginErrorAction("foo");
```

You are creating a class in a sense that you can use the `new`-operator (which can be used on any `function` in JavaScript) - but your *class* is not a *class* in the sense of qualifying as a Typescript-type.

Technically speaking: You cannot use any `const/let` as a `type`.

If you want to keep creating classes dynamically, I guess you will still have to at least name an interface for each one. - Or you don't set explicit types but let TypeScript's type-inferencing-system handle it - you should be able to still get the code-completion for any property on your anonymous class without setting an explicit type.

Comment: I don't need the types for auto-complete. I need them because I often need to check the instance of a certain object and then depending on the result execute different operations...Let's see if someone else comes up with a trick and otherwise I will probably need to create an Interface for each one as you said.

Comment: Checking of the instance should still work, if you mean: `foo instanceof LoginErrorAction` - since `instanceof` is not a typescript-specific operation but a native javascript operation - I'm wondering though where you would need to do something like this in the context of ngrx

Comment: Also, why not just test the type of the ErrorAction? `foo.type === ActionTypes.LOGIN_ERROR`.